# Does CPANEL offer a schedule backups for Files and Databases content?

Tags: backup, cpanel, ms-sql

I would like to know if it is possible to use cPanel to set up automatic scheduled backup for all my content and configuration of my cPanel account, basically I need to backup files and DataBases (I am using MS SQL).

Using cPanel I see an option, Domains Configuration and content (All configuration and content). Is this option right for my requirement?

http://support.easyhost1.com/kb/a55/how-to-use-backup-manager?KBSearchID=308

Comment: This is a question you should be asking your hosting provider.  Backup varies from host provider to host provider.

Comment: @rrirower thanks for your comment, hosting provider told me that it is up to me to use the "cPanel Backup manager" provided by them. Problem is I am not sure I am able to backup files and DB together, using a schedule task. I know it is possible using a manual db backup but I need automatic backups. Do you have an idea if it is possible to make it using cPanel? Thanks

Comment: My hosting provider runs that task automatically on a regular basis.  And, it does back up everything.  I can also run it manually whenever I need to.  Maybe your provider does the same thing.

Comment: @rrirower thanks, for your comment, do you use cPanel? Which version? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I use _cPanel Pro 1.0 (RC1)_.

Comment: IMHO, the best way it's create your own backup system. You can made on bash, perl or PHP. Where you feel more comfortable. Put your trust in the system backups or your hosting Cpanel is a very typical recklessness of these times. I've been 20 years in the world of hosting, and you say, do backups cpanel, have its own system with rsync, and placed the copies in two different datacenter. And I tell my clients: please have your own set of backups. I have seen many sysad mourn, and many porpietarios of websites. IMHO